# Nix error trying to install correct GHC version for Plutus

Tags: plutus, nix, ghc

As recommended by [Haskell/Nix expert lan Burzynski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgkAwiyxSxA), I'm trying to use Nix install the correct GHC version for Plutus as follows:

```
nix shell nixpkgs#haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal nixpkgs#cabal-install
```

However I get the following

```
error: flake 'flake:nixpkgs' does not provide attribute 
packages.x86_64-linux.haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal', 
'legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal' or 
'haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the compiler using `nix-shell -p haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal` seems to work. Can't explain why though. I guess it is related to where nix looks for the package.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I thought that commands that contain "-" like nix-shell were deprecated. Is it possible to use "nix-shell" to install ghc and then use "nix shell" thereafter for Plutus development?

Comment: You are correct. So I think I know what is causing this. The package `haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal` is only available in the 23.05 channel and not in the unstable channel. You might have configured your nix to use the nixpkgs-unstable as the default channel, which errors because it is not there. Forcing nix to use the 23.05 channel like so `nix shell github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-23.05#haskell.compiler.ghc8107BinaryMinimal` will proceed to install the package in your shell. I think `nix-shell` uses the 23.05 channel by default, which is why that command worked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I don't get the error message anymore, but after downloading, the process just exits without taking me into the nix shell.

Comment: Yeah, in fact that is the expected behavior and you are placed in a nix shell, but with the exception that you keep your existing shell environment with the addition that the downloaded package has been made available to your shell. Running `ghc --version` should succeed using the correct version. You can exit out of that nix shell by sending the EOF character using `ctrl+d`.